# Why do repeated trigonometric operations approach seemingly arbitrary limits?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, recreational-mathematics

So I was messing around on my iPhone calculator trying to find the the precision of the calculator by finding at what point sin(x) was equal to x. I found myself repeating the sine function sin(sin(sin(....sin(x)...)))). Predictably the limit of this repeated operation of taking the sine was 0.

I then wondered what would happen if I did the same thing with cos(x). Theoretically it should approach 1 since it cos(x) <= 1 and the cosine of that would be even closer to 1. However, since only cos(0) would yield one I expected that the result would be close to 1, but not exactly 1. At this point I realized that it made a difference between radians and degrees, so I chose degrees and took the cosine repeatedly of an arbitrary number and I found that this yielded a result of roughly .999847741531088... each time. Stunningly, it also approached this limit relatively quickly, usually being close after only 4 cosine operations.

I found that using radians also produced a similar limit of around .73906... but it took much longer to approach this value. I messed around and found other limits and interesting behavior by taking other patterns like sin(cos(sin(cos(...(cos(x)...)))).

Why do these limits exist, and what is special about these particular numbers?

I know this is not rigorous mathematics, but I think it is interesting that such limits exist, especially the .9998477... limit for repeated cosine operations in degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out these values aren't arbitrary. Rather, they are the approximate solutions to $\cos x = x$ in radians and degrees.

(In the last line of your post you mean "...for repeated **cosine** operations in degrees".)

Comment: Ahh! perfect. That makes sense.

Comment: Fixed point in the recursive dynamics. I strongly recommend [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Nonlinear-Dynamics-Chaos-Applications-Nonlinearity/dp/0813349109/ref=dp_ob_title_bk).