# What is the importance of this value?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

So I was messing around with desmos, and I noticed that as I iterated $cos(sin(cos(sin(...(x)...)))$, the graph seemed to approach a straight line, at around the value $0.76816470891$. (I'm using radians)

I was wondering what is the significance of this value, and does it have any practical application?

[Picture of my desmos graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba153.png)

**Edit**: I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419759/sin-cos-sin-cos-sin-cos-cdots-sin-cos-x-cdots), but it did not seem to entirely answer my question. For what it's worth, the value in that post is the value i get when I compute the sine of $0.76816...$

Comment: $\sin(\cos(\sin(\cos(\dots$ is not the same thing as $\cos(\sin(\cos(\sin(\dots$.  Your image and your body are different.

Comment: There is no significance of that value: it's just a fixed point for the function $\sin ( \cos( \cdot ))$

Comment: ah, I must have typed it wrong. Will fix

Comment: Supposing that such a limit $\ell$ exists (*you can prove that by showing it is monotone and bounded, if it happens to be the case*), then it would necessarily satisfy $\cos(\sin(\ell))=\ell$.  One can approximate $\ell$ using numerical methods.

Comment: So then... the question is... what is the difference between your post and the post you linked to?  (*other than yours being about $\cos(\sin(\cos(\dots$ versus $\sin(\cos(\sin(\dots$*)  Just asking if it is significant for any practical purposes?  Very likely not...

Comment: Presumably this shows up for everyone else in "Related" as well, but worth pointing out this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146060/. JMoravitz's second comment is in the same spirit as the answer given there.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky yes that question seemed to be more on point with what I was trying to ask